# target all parents(".class") of a specific class jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

I am having trouble targeting all parents that have a specific class set.

If I click on george michael, I want to, say, change the color of the `<p>` tag containing "michael" and "george sr".

Below is dummy html and the jQuery that failed.

```
<ul>
<li><div class="leaf"><p>george sr</p></div>
<ul>
    <li><div class="leaf"><p>michael</p></div>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="leaf"><p>george michael</p></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div class="leaf"><p>gob</p></div>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="leaf"><p>steve holt</p></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div class="leaf"><p>lindsay</p></div>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="leaf"><p>maeby</p></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do:

```
$(document).on("click", '.leaf', function() {
   $(this).parents(".leaf").children('p').css('color','red');
});
```

edit request: also, can someone explain why the above jquery does not work?

Please help :)

for your use: http://jsfiddle.net/KuZrq/2/

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the `leaf` `div`s aren't ancestors of each other, they're siblings to the `ul`s that contain other `leaf` `div`s. Your code should work if you give the `leaf` class directly to the `li`s instead.

Answer (score 2):

like this :

```
$(document).on("click", '.leaf', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').parents('li').find('> .leaf > p').css('color', 'red');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uEFq5/1/)

Comment: What you did works, but I found a better method, which I'm going to use.  Thank you!